# overflow: auto is messing up the width of my window

Tags: html, css, visualforce

The Css goes like this:

```
#mylog{
    background-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(154,154,154);
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

as soon as I put the 'overflow: auto;' the width gets reduced. I have no clue why one tag would overcome the other. Please help.

Comment: add display: block; and clearfix, clear: both; sometimes that helps.

Comment: Posting a single rule of CSS in this context won't help much, please post *all* relevant code or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example.

Answer (score 0):

When the box height of your **#mylog** element is overflowed, your **overflow:auto** declaration will in force the browser to generate a vertical scrollbar which will use some pixels of the available width.

If you don't want the available width to change when overflowing, you should use **overflow:scroll** and in that way, your scroll bar will be all ways there and your available width wont be changed.

Comment: Fico, I even tried using overflow:scroll, and it is giving me the same issue

Comment: Is the width still changing?. Then please, post your involved HTML code and CSS as well in order to see the full picture. if not , I am not able to go forward.

Comment: Hello Fico, thanks for the reply and I am sorry to get back this late. I figured out the reason and the reason was that the image component width was interfering with the width of my box. I reduced the width of the image and overflow:scroll  works fine.